# Certain PHP post data not accessible when posting different types

Tags: php, mysql, post

```
<form id="fileform" action="php/upload2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <input name="upload[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" class="form-control-file text-white"> 
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label><b class="text-white">Generated Identifier</b></label>
        <input type="text" id="generatedidentifier" name="ab" class="form-control" disabled="">
    </div>
</form>
```

I have a form that sends both files and a string to my server, I have no problem accessing and using the files but my string(named "ab") isn't recognized by PHP!

I use this to verify that the data from "ab" isn't being sent properly:

```
if (isset($_POST["ab"])) {
    $identifier = $_POST["ab"];
    echo $identifier;
    echo " is the ID";
} else {
    $identifier = null;
    echo "no ID supplied";
}
```

**CAUSE**
Input had a "disabled" attribute, which prevented the data to be transferred to my php

Comment: So ALL the data is put into $_FILES for some reason?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that all data is't a FILE. I have both FILES and STRING(?) going through the form, and the string isn't accessible for some reason.

Comment: for ur sake, what should be the value of `$_POST["ab"]` ? as for your code the value is empty

Comment: @RiggsFolly I think you might be misunderstanding.  OP says "I have no problem accessing and using the files".  So OP is only claiming that they are not getting any value in `$_POST["ab"]`

Comment: @dean a 9-digit string, 876574898 ex..

Comment: Could it then be because `<input type="text" name="ab" disabled="">` **is disabled**?

Comment: @zugo123456789 if the digit is created by php script, why dont you call you code as the value of `$_POST["ab"]` instead.

Comment: @dean digit is created by javascript, not created by any php script

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yep.. That was it..

Comment: Okay, out put the JS value in php and call it as a valuable to your `$_POST["ab"]` its doable @zugo123456789

Comment: Sorry I got all confused and wandered all round the houses :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at this line

```
<input type="text" id="generatedidentifier" name="ab" class="form-control" disabled="">
```

You have disabled that input. Disabled inputs are not sent to the PHP